# How to get single value of DF

Tags: python, pandas

**I have following situation:**

```
id=id["ID"]
print(id)
```

**Result:**
`0    7161 <br>Name: ID, dtype: int64`

**And I need just:**
`7161`

How to do it?

`id["ID"]` - is a result of filtering data frame and always include only 1 record.

**How I am trying to use it:**

*#Identifying client list limited to "1" record with done highest run-over on the shop with certain time scales.*
`id = calc.most_value(df_orders,1)`

*#Getting stats for user reg monthly orders etc.*
`order_history_month = calc.client_stats(id,df_orders)`

**ERROR**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sebastianhaja/PycharmProjects/nbn-poc/main.py", line 58, in <module>
    order_history_month = calc.client_stats(id["ID"],df_orders)
  File "/Users/sebastianhaja/PycharmProjects/nbn-poc/calc.py", line 59, in client_stats
    result = orders[orders["member_id"]==id]
  File "/Users/xxx/PycharmProjects/c24-/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/common.py", line 65, in new_method
    return method(self, other)
  File "/Users/xxx/PycharmProjects/c24-/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/arraylike.py", line 29, in __eq__
    return self._cmp_method(other, operator.eq)
  File "/Users/xxx/PycharmProjects/c24-/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 4973, in _cmp_method
    raise ValueError("Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects")
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Thank you for Help

Seb

Answer (score 1):

You can use `iloc` or `iat`:

```py
>>> id["ID"].iloc[0]
```

Comment: 9 second later, dont worry, I guess your solution will be accepted.

Comment: @jezrael, I was also writing the same thing which I learnt from you times ago, so I don't have any problem on its removal (the part containing `next` and `iter`). after all, I learnt it from you :)

Comment: @ThePyGuy - Ok, if you want, add some edit for remove my name ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
new=id["ID"].iat[0]
new=id["ID"].to_numpy()[0]
new=id["ID"].tolist()[0]
```

If possible not match use `iter` with `next` trick:

```
new = next(iter(id["ID"]), 'no match')
```